# unsupported SEXPTYPE: 19

Tags: r, google-maps, google-api

I am trying to extract the travel time and the distance between two points using R but for some reason, I have the following error.

```
library(ggmap)
list <-  mapdist("Hamilton, ontraio, Canada", "Toronto, Ontario, Canada",mode="driving") 
res <- list$hour
```

The Error I Have

```
ist <- mapdist("Hamilton, ontraio, Canada", "Toronto, Ontario, Canada",mode="driving")
by using this function you are agreeing to the terms at :
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/distancematrix/


unsupported SEXPTYPE: 19
Information from URL : http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Hamilton+ontraio+Canada&destinations=Toronto+Ontario+Canada&mode=driving&sensor=false
Error in `*tmp*`[[c(1, 1)]] : subscript out of bounds
```

Any ideas on how to solve it ?????

Comment: I can't. I'm not getting that error. Using ggmap Version: 2.6.1 on R 3.4.3 on a Mac with El Cap.

Comment: I'm not getting error either. Using `ggmap` version 2.6.1 on a window PC.

Comment: So weird !!, Any ideas on how to fix this error????
I am using the same version ggmap 2.6.1 on my laptop windows 10

Comment: See this https://github.com/dkahle/ggmap/issues/217

Comment: I got the same error when using fromJSON() of rjson package. Reinstall rjson package solved my problem.